# Is there any way to run insert query in all database schemas in parallel?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, nestjs, schema, multi-tenant

I am using Postgres, and in my project and I am using schemas to separate data logically. And these schemas are created dynamically as new customer comes, and all these schemas have the same table.

So is there any way in which I can run insert, update, delete and get query from all schemas in an efficient way?

Comment: You have to start multiple database sessions if you want to modify data in parallel.

Comment: yes I know this solution but this one is not efficient way, I want better way. I am using sequelize and nestjs

Comment: There is no other way. Why do you think it would not be efficient?